# How to export SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a beginner in learning SQL and i am just wondering if i happen to build a database for let's say a customer. How would i actually give the completed database to the customer ?

For example, the customer is a school and i made a database of their students and teachers in SQL then in what ways i could give the completed database to the school authority.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Depends on the DB you use.

Comment: Being that you've tagged 3 separate db types in your question, you'll have to clarify before anyone can give you any sort of answer....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have added tags for multiple different flavours of SQL. Please pick which one your question applies to.

Comment: SQL is a broad range of specific dialects each of which are often quite different in practice, and the tooling for each is wildly different. Please pick one and only one when asking questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is for sql server steps for you . After step 6 you have 2 more finalization steps to confirm all you have done. Your restore sql code is towards the end after step 6

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
RESTORE DATABASE [db_name] FROM DISK = 'X:\MSSQL\Data\FullBackups\db_name.bak' WITH RECOVERY
```

Comment: Thank you so much Junketsu !

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to take a backup of the database. The backup file can then be passed to the customer and restored in their environment.

Depending on your SQL flavour the backup and restore commands may differ.

However if you are just intending to pass data from the school hosted database to the local authority, then you would want to export the data to a format that the LA can support (e.g. CSV or XML).

Comment: Or, in SQL Server you can right-click the database, Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> "Script entire database and all database objects", and save it somewhere as a .sql file that can be run on the client's server. That will create the database objects without any data.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Appreciate it Iainc and Russel Fox

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand the problem but if this is for an application with a small database, and by small I mean about a dozen table, I build would it using an embedded database such as SQLite. That way you your application will come complete with a built-in database all developed into one executable file. I have worked with SQLite in the past and it is a very robust database that can store and retrieve very large data sets. It also interfaces quite well with other languages such as Perl, C++, Java, etc. You may be surprise to find out how many of your current phone apps come complete with a backend database embedded in them.